# which index approach is better in my case?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, database-administration

In a table I have 4 columns:

```
(a(int),b(int),c(var-char),d(var-char))
```

I have two query as follows:

```
select *from table where a=1 and b=2 and c="abc";

select *from table where a=1 and b=2 and d="zyz";
```

Now Index approach:

- index on (a,b,c)
- index on (a,b,d)

OR

- index on(a,b)
- index on(c)
- index on(d)

Which one is better approach ?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. The choice of index will be based on the selectivity of data you have in tables and the cost of maintaining the index. Noone can give you an answer not knowing those.

Comment: @JakubKania I want to know ,  does my second indexing approach will work ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: You should rather ask questions like: How many distinct values do you have? How many distinct values do you have in one particular column? Isn't table scan better in the end? (Sometimes it performs much better).

Comment: @JiriS I have 30GB of data ,so table scan is not good . and the columns are not unique .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to try it. It's impossible to say which indexes are better unless you know what's the data you're planning to work with. The best is to create the table, insert some sampled data and then do a few typical queries with `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

An example would be

`EXPLAIN select *from table where a=1 and b=2 and c="abc";`

`EXPLAIN select *from table where a=1 and b=2 and d="zyz";`

or

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE select *from table where a=1 and b=2 and c="abc";`

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE select *from table where a=1 and b=2 and d="zyz";`

See as well http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: I have 30GB of data ,so table scan is not good . and the columns are not unique .